# I have a widget area in my header. How can I have that display a different widget depending on what group is shown?

Tags: widgets, buddypress

I have a widget area in my header. How can I have that display a different widget depending on what group is shown?  So if uses are in a group about say Baseball in the site Header in my theme the Widget on Baseball shows up but if the user is in a group on Golf then the header shows a widget I have for Golf? Can this be done?

Comment: Is this a Buddypress question?

Comment: Yes. Groups in Buddypress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install [widget logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) and add something like `bp_is_groups_component() && 'your-group' == bp_current_item()` in a widget's widget logic area.

The widget logic content filter feature looks like it could create something a bit more sophisticated than the above